# calculating hours based on date range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've been trying to create a nested IF statement that will total the amount of hours based on a date range and the start / finish time (similar to a time sheet).
This calculates hours "worked" based on, if the hours are continuously worked or part of each day.
I've managed to get this returning the correct result based on a range of variables, however it is returning an incorrect result for one variable where it adds an excess amount of hours as it counts the total range of hours against the next day.  This is where the start time is greater than the finish time and goes into the following date(s) (IE: A night shift).

Appreciate any suggestions as I've tried removing the `+1` from the `D12-B12+1` which results in returning an incorrect value for other entries.

I hope this makes sense.

Code:

```
=IF(F12="Yes",(P12-O12) * 24 *K12, IF(F12="No",(MOD(E12-C12,1)) * 24 * (IF(AND(D12=B12+1,E12<C12),+1,D12-B12+1)) * K12,0))
```

[Link to cell](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ac_Lq5WcsCBkX58Ay5sUg3mirOjGZe1uwxuXDNwwkYY/edit#gid=1055929886&range=Q12)

Comment: 04/07/2022 06:00:00 08/07/2022 10:00:00 is it a shift or  continuous shift ?

Comment: That would be a shift based on the value of column F (yes or no). If No it will multiply the hours by the days between 2 dates to calculate the total of hours, unfortunately it is counting an extra day based on time/date values.

Comment: Hi TTVH, There is no need to add another column with yes or no. the formula will do just that. check the detail tab so you can recreate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to calculate hours based on start date start time end date, end time, what you did is concatenated the date and time this solution dosent need concatenation or even "24 Hour Continuous Coverage?" input
I simplified the problem so it can be used in diffrent circumstances, take a look at the [**Example Sheet.**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12u8x4q5JYgFNjgHyCtfM-ToEU_wFpOqnp9uB0P10jF8/edit?usp=sharing)

### Format fix

- Before we start we need to fix:
  The finish time here is set as a date.

[image]

> It need's to be set like this

[image]

> Go to Format > Custom Date and time and set it Hour : Minute : Second.

[image]

> And set the **Hours** in your case `Q2` to **Elapsed** Hour : Minute : Second

[image]

### The **Formula**

> Paste this on the column of "Hours" in your case `Q2`

```
=IF(IF(C2=E2=TRUE,C2=E2,C2>E2)=TRUE,IFS(AND(C2=0,C2=E2),1,E2<C2,((1-C2)+E2),1=1,E2-C2)*DATEDIF(B2,D2,"D"),(IFS(AND(C2=0,C2=E2),1,E2<C2,((1-C2)+E2),1=1,E2-C2)*DATEDIF(B2,D2,"D"))+IFS(AND(C2=0,C2=E2),1,E2<C2,((1-C2)+E2),1=1,E2-C2))
```

[image]

### Steps

This is seemingly intimidating when you look at the nested fuctions but once you see this [**Example Sheet.**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12u8x4q5JYgFNjgHyCtfM-ToEU_wFpOqnp9uB0P10jF8/edit?usp=sharing) you can reimplement it in your project. check the Steps Tab.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.
I've taken a look and still seem to encounter the same problem.
This is where the 18/07/2022 21:00 to 20/07/2022 09:00 should only equate to 24:00:00 hours but is returning 36:00:00 hours.
It seems to be an issue when the start time is later than the finish time. H12 on your sheet.

Comment: @TTVH It should be fixed now.<br>18/07/2022 21:00:00 20/07/2022 09:00:00  24:00:00.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts.  The formula seems to be encountering the same problem as mine from a different angle.  It's really stumping me.  In your sheet its returned the correct value in G12, but shorted the value of the other cells in column G, which is the same as what I was getting.  With my formula, my thought was (IF(AND(D12=B12+1,E12<C12),+1,**D12-B12+1**)) <--- the 2nd logical value would only +1 if E12>C12, otherwise it would just be D12-B12

Comment: @TTVH 1 - what you mean by sorted, 2 - cant you write the desierd output in the sheet i provided? in steps tab.

Comment: @TTVH i mean shorted

Comment: shorted meaning it calculates a day shorter than it should IE: 0 days instead of 1 for cell K9.  If I +1 the day, then for K12 it will return 3 instead of 2 as the working hours go into the following day.  I've put the desired output here:  [![Capture.jpg](https://i.postimg.cc/GpRPswxW/Capture.jpg)](https://postimg.cc/YvXLJPVR)

Comment: @TTVH Pheww, finally.

Comment: wow, unbelievable effort.  I didn't have the knowledge or thought to create it like you have.  It definitely works.  Thankyou for your time in problem solving this, it really had me stumped.  I did notice if I changed the start / finish values to say 9:00 and 9:00 to make up 24 hours, it returns the number as zero, although this could be countered by using the concatenate portion of the original formula to measure the amount.  Thanks again for your tireless effort, I'm sure it will be useful for many in the future also.

Comment: I've been trying to formulate how to calculate total hours but exclude weekends (or public holiday for eg) as my next side project.
I've chipped away with this formula but is not having any luck.
Thought I'd put it out there as I may be missing something simple!
=IF(OR($E$2<$C$2,P2<O2),0,(NETWORKDAYS(O2,P2)-(NETWORKDAYS(O2,O2)*IF(MOD(O2,1)>$E$2,1,(MAX($C$2,MOD(O2,1))-$C$2)/($E$2-$C$2)))-(NETWORKDAYS(O2,O2)*IF(MOD(P2,1)<$C$2,1,($E$2-MIN($E$2,MOD(P2,1)))/($E$2-$C$2))))*($E$2-$C$2)*24)